# detect outgoing call end state in broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcastreceiver, phone-call

I am using broadcastreceiver to detect the outgoing call and start a service once it started dialing.Service is started. Now i want to stop the service once call ends or dialing ends.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL.equals(intent.getAction())) {

        intent = new Intent(context, serv.class);
        context.startService(intent);
   }

    if(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
            TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
        intent = new Intent(context, serv.class);
        context.stopService(intent);

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    try {
                //to Fix Lolipop broadcast issue.
                long subId = intent.getLongExtra("subscription", Long.MIN_VALUE);
                if (subId < Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
                        savedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
                    } else {
                        String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                        String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                        int state = 0;
                        if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;

                        } else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;

                        } else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
                        }
                        onCallStateChanged(context, state, number);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }


public void onCallStateChanged(final Context context, int state, String number) {
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    isIncoming = true;
                    callStartTime = new Date();
                    savedNumber = number;


                    TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            onIncomingCallStarted(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);

                        }
                    };
                    Timer t = new Timer();
                    t.schedule(tt, 1000);
//                    TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {
//                        @Override
//                        public void run() {
//                        }
//                    };
//                    onIncomingCallStarted(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    if (lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                        isIncoming = true;
                        callStartTime = new Date();
                        onReceiveCall(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, "received");
                    } else {
                        isIncoming = false;
                    }
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    if (lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {

                        onMissedCall(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, "Missed");
                    } else if (isIncoming) {
                        onIncomingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
                    } else {
                        onOutgoingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date(), "outgoing");
                    }
                    break;
            }
        lastState = state;

    }
```